# how can i write the aggregation query for te below context in nodejs for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to write a query to fetch the data from mongodb, I have three collections --books, teachers, students. Book collection have bookName and_id, teachers collection have -- teacherName and teacherId, student collection have _id, studentName, teacherId…. I have studentName as S1 and teacherName as T1 with me, how can I fetch the student record with the name S1 which also have the teacherId as the name T1 (from the teacher collection) from the student collection... eg.I need to fetch books _id with name given from the books collection and from teachers and students I have to apply, select _id from student where studentName =S1 and teacherId=(select techerID from techer where teacherName = T1)… how can I write this query in node using aggregation--below is my code, can someone help me to correct my code

```
books.aggregate([{
  '$match': {
    'name': 'book1'
  }
}, {
  '$lookup': {
    {
      from: students,
      '$match': {

        'name': 'Annie'
      }
    },
    'from': 'teachers', // collection name of the teachers
    'localField': 'teacherId',
    'foreignField': '_id',
    'as': 'teachers'
  }
}, {
  '$match': {
    'teachers': {
      '$elemMatch': {
        'teacherName': 'Jones'
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

eg..

```
books 
ID1, physics
ID2, chemistry

tecaher 
t1, zed
t2, tom

student 
s1, annie, zed(//teacher name)
s2, john, zed
s3, leya, tom
```

i have already inserted books and teachers collections
now i have to get the student record such that, it will have name as s1 and teacherid as the id of zed of the teacher collection ,but need the id of techer Zed from techer collection and id of physics book  from book collection...
so i started like books.agregate(matching the bookname) then lookup to student--but student have only the name of the teaher with that i have to find the teacher id from teacher collection...
I have to insert id, name, teacherid into student record

Comment: Could you post few examples from each collection instead of explaining? That will be better way to imagine for us.

Comment: Could you add how does your current collection looks like and what is your expected output?

Comment: Initially `student` collection has `_id`, 'name', and 'teacher_id', now you want to add another field as `teacher_name` to this collection. Is this what you want? Please clarify.

Comment: I have s1, annie, zed with me I have to get the profile of the student which have name as annie and the teacherId  as the id of the zed from teacher record

Comment: Yes, could you update the same with few more examples, like how your expected output should look like.

Comment: expected output--s1, annie, t1

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `$lookup` operator in wrong way, please refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for more information and examples.

The following query will be helpful for you:

```
db.student.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "teacher",
      localField: "teacher_name",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "teacher_details"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$teacher_details"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      teacher_id: "$teacher_details._id"
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "s1",
    "name": "annie",
    "teacher_id": "t1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "s2",
    "name": "john",
    "teacher_id": "t1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "s3",
    "name": "leya",
    "teacher_id": "t2"
  }
]
```